# Why does this code not create a heat map in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have a data frame `df` that looks like:

```
                team_1   team_2   team_3
very_effective   3        5        8
effective        5        6        9  
ineffective      6        8        20
```

I want to create a heatmap that has different colour squares which are darker if the value is higher. I tried the following code but I get the error `object 'X1' is not found`. Does anyone know how to fix? Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(df, aes(X1, X2)) +                           # Create heatmap with ggplot2
  geom_tile()
ggp
```

Comment: Replace X1 with team_1, and so on. The error is telling you that X1 does not exist in df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aes()` expects vectors for x- and y-values; not a crosstable, and also not undefined variables:

> Usage
> aes(x, y, ...)

source: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html

As a general rule, ggplot() expects all the data in [long format](https://www.statology.org/long-vs-wide-data/).

##### Solution

Given the following data:

```r
df <- structure(list(team_1 = c(3L, 5L, 6L), team_2 = c(5L, 6L, 8L), 
    team_3 = c(8L, 9L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("very_effective", 
"effective", "ineffective"))
```

We first add the row names as a column, as a factor to preserve their row order. Then we melt the data from a crosstable into long format:

```r
df_plot <- df

df_plot$effect <- factor(rownames(df_plot), levels = rownames(df_plot))

df_plot <- reshape2::melt(df_plot)
```

Resulting data frame:

```r
> df_plot
          effect variable value
1 very_effective   team_1     3
2      effective   team_1     5
3    ineffective   team_1     6
4 very_effective   team_2     5
5      effective   team_2     6
6    ineffective   team_2     8
7 very_effective   team_3     8
8      effective   team_3     9
9    ineffective   team_3     2
```

ggplot is happy to accept this data format.

On the y-axis, it will put the 'lowest' value of `effect` (the first value in the factor: 'very effective') on the bottom; with `scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)` we reverse the order.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=variable, y=effect, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to keep the order on the heat map so that we have `very_effective`, `effective` and then `ineffective` rather than having `effective` at the end?

Comment: @CheckThis Yes that would be very much preferred indeed. I've added it!